# Обработка формы ajax запросом (проверка на дубль в БД)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть форма, `<form id="main" action="add_charge.php" method="post">...</form>`

Есть обработчик сабмит:

```
$("#main").submit(function(){
    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
        if(confirm(data)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $.post('../ajax/checkdouble.php', {amount: $("input[name=amount]").val(), project_id: $("select[name=project_id]").val()}, onAjaxSuccess);
});
```

В checkdouble.php делаю запрос к БД, где проверяю на наличие такой же записи. Задача: если запись есть вывести запрос на подтверждение добавления и соответственно добавить или вернуться к редактированию. Проблема в том, что код работает, если сделать обработчик например онклик какого-нибудь объекта, т.е. работает AJAX проверка, но не работает отправка формы. Если делать на сабмит форм, то AJAX не работает, т.к. происходит переход на обработку формы.

Comment: Вот так: `$('form').on('submit', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); /* ... */});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыли отменить стандартную отправку формы:

```
$("#main").submit(function(){

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
        if(confirm(data)) {
            $("#main").append("<input type='hidden' name='submit_charge' value='1' />");
            $("#main")[0].submit(); // !!! submit without handler
        }
    }

    $.post(
      '../ajax/checkdouble.php', 
      { 
        amount: $("input[name=amount]").val(), 
        project_id: $("select[name=project_id]").val() 
      }, 
      onAjaxSuccess
    );

    return false; // !!! cancel submit through this handler
});
```

А `return`-ы из `onAjaxSuccess` не нужны. К тому времени обработчик `submit` давно уже отработает.

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало все кроме обработки формы. Вначале файла, в котором форма, стандартный обработчик:     if(isset($_POST['submit_charge'])) {....}, страница при нажатии Ок на вопрос добавить перезагружается, но в этот обработчик не попадает.

Comment: `submit_charge` - это имя кнопки, которая отправляет форму?

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: Не может в `$_POST` быть этого ключа. Вы же теперь форму отправляете не по нажатию кнопки, а кодом.

Comment: C append'ом ожило! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @AndreyPetrov На здоровье. Галочка - слева от ответа. Успехов!